# Writing Rails Gems: Proper way to add to existing rails modules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm just getting started with rails gems, and wondering how best to add functionality to existing rails modules. For example, if I wanted to add a new form helper, I'd typically do something like this:

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  # My form defs in here
end
```

But I'm wondering if that's the most elegant way of doing things - especially if, for example, I'm going to wrap the new functionality up in a gem.

For example, suppose I'm creating the gem "MyGem", and I only want its functionality to be present if the gem is called in the controller. So in the controller I add 'include MyGem', and in the lib/my_gem.rb I'd typically do something like:

```
# lib/my_gem.rb
module MyGem
  # My form defs in here
end
```

The question is: what is the standard way for overwriting defs in the ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder module from within the MyGem module?

Cheers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a Class with inheritance of `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` you can override all method from FormBuilder you want.

You can add other method too.

After you just need use this FormBuilder when you create your form with option `:builder` Or you can do an helper method like `simple_form_for` to call the `form_for` method with your builder.

If you want do in a module you need create your class in module

```
# lib/my_gem.rb
require 'my_gem/form_builder'

# lib/my_gem/form_builder.rb
module MyGem
  class FormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    # form def
  end
end
```

In your builder you use `:builder => MyGem::FormBuilder`

Comment: Hi shingara - thanks for the quick response. It works great when inheriting from classes such as ::FormBuilder, but in modules such as (for example) ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper, where the methods aren't wrapped in a class, I get the good old "wrong argument type Module (expected Class)". It's what threw me off initially - perhaps my question is how to inherit from methods in modules without a class?

Comment: PS: Just to pre-empt: Interested in ::FormHelper For the purpose of modifying 'form_for'. I'm aware the internal builders should be modified in ::FormBuilder. ;-)